# Does using 'grade' fit here in this context?

Tags: word-request

I was looking at the [Area51's page of ELL](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). It has the valuable statistics about the ELL site like **Visits per day**, **Question per day** categories and for each category it says what is the expected value and how we are doing as compared to that value.

> **Okay** – 15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users keep coming back.
>
> **Needs Work** – 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work. A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

What is the correct word to describe **Okay**, **Needs Work** for each category? Is using **grade for each category** correct?

Answer (score 2):

I would understand you if you called it a "grade", but usually a grade doesn't change as often as these statistics do.  You're given a grade on a test, and that grade doesn't change. A restaurant is given an inspection grade, and that doesn't change until the next time they're inspected.  These statistics chance so often that, to my ear, *grade* sounds too permanent.

So: the numbers themselves are our statistics.  I think that the Okay/Needs Work etc could best be referred to as a *ranking* or *score*.

> Q: How are we ranked on daily visits?
>
> A: Not very well; we're still at "Needs Work."

Or:

> Q: What's our score for percentage of questions answered?
>
> A: We're doing really well with that, our score is "Excellent"!

If we called it a *grade*, the exchange would go something like this:

> Q: What's our current grade on ELL's question-to-answer ratio?
>
> A: We're at 2.3 answers per question, so just "Okay."

I would understand what you meant, but it sounds a bit awkward to my ear.

Answer (score 1):

*[Grade](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grade#Noun)* (“The performance of an individual or group on an examination or test, expressed by a number, letter, or other symbol; a score”) is ok, as are   *[rating](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rating#Noun)* (“A position on a scale” or “An evaluation of status”),  *[assessment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assessment#Noun)* (“An [appraisal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appraisal#Noun) or [evaluation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evaluation#Noun)”), and  *[score](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/score#Noun)* (“The performance of an individual or group on an examination or test, expressed by a number, letter, or other symbol; a grade”).  Of these terms, I prefer *rating*, because I find it more suggestive of an evaluation expressed in words, rather than as a letter (eg, a letter grade) or a number (eg, a numeric score).  (But note that *rating* also has the sense “A number, letter, or other mark that refers to the ability of something”, which offsets my reason for preferring it.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Can 'status' be used in place of 'grade'?

Comment: @JoeDimaggio, there may be cases where it can be, but I think more commonly than not, *[status](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/status#Noun)* and *[grade](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grade#Noun)* can't interchange.

Comment: I am sorry, what I meant was can 'status' be used here?

Comment: @JoeDimaggio, yes, regarding the original question about “Is using *grade for each category* correct?”, I think *status for each category* might be preferable.  In that phrase,  I slightly prefer *rating* to *status* and prefer *status* to *grade*.